# Is this a peak detector or an envelope detector?

Tags: diodes, filter

I have a tailing part of circuit that has these elements.  The signal passes through an inverting amplifier and goes to the diode:

[image]

I did some research, and found that some parts look like a peak detector or an envelope detector, but they include 2-3 elements at most, like R1 and C1.

I was thinking R2-C3 could be a RC filter or something like that, I get confused about that.

Answer (score 0):

D1-C1 forms a peak detector. R1-C2 is a passive low pass filter with a cutoff of \$\frac{1}{2\times\pi\times10000\times10^-9}\$ = 15.9 kHz. If you prefer a DC signal across C2, then increasing the cutoff might be a good idea. Let the voltage across C2 (as well as R2) be \$V_2\$

The output at the node shown in red (wrto GND) will be same as \$V_2\$ due to the capacitor C3 being open.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit you have at hands can be both a peak detector and an envelope detector. It depends on component values and the specific application. Without knowing the complete circuit in which it is used it's impossible to say.

First of all you must understand that *peak detector* and *envelope detector* describe a circuit *function*, not its actual structure.

And ideal peak detector could be made by just an (ideal) diode in series with an (ideal) cap, like D1+C1 in your schematic, and taking the output across the cap. Assuming the load across the cap has infinite impedance, such an *ideal* circuit will always output the maximum voltage it has ever seen at its input. Not very useful in most applications unless you have a way to *reset* the detector.

One way to reset the peak detector is to place a switch across the cap (usually a transistor if the operation is to be automated). Activate the switch and the cap is discharged. Deactivate the switch and the cap can go back to its job of storing the (new) peak voltage.

Now, another simple way to "reset" the detector is to apply a lower impedance load across the cap, so that its charge slowly decays in time.
In this way the detector is never "hard reset": it's output will slowly follow the peaks of the input signal.

How slowly? It depends on the time constant of the resulting RC circuit, i.e. the capacity of the cap times whatever resistance the cap "sees".
But how do you *choose* the time constant, that is the decay time? It depends on the application.

Now, if the input signal is an AM modulated signal and the decay time is slow (much bigger) compared with the period of the carrier frequency, but it is fast compared to the variations of the modulating signal (envelope), here you have an AM demodulator, i.e. an envelope detector.

In your case everything after the diode acts as an RC filter that can be used to "filter out" the carrier frequency. The fact that the output is taken through a cap, i.e. is AC coupled with the load (of which we know nothing) is a strong hint the output is an AC signal, so your circuit may well be used as some sort of envelope detector.

Now the following is an LTspice simulation of your circuit in which I added an high impedance load and a 5MHz sinusoidal input signal (the carrier) modulated with a 10kHz sinusoidal signal:

[image]

and these are the simulation results:

[image]

As it is evident, the output is the modulating signal, i.e. the envelope of the modulated carrier.